# How to check if any element of array in another array?

Tags: d

I have got string `aabbccddffgg` I need to check if it have at last one element from array: `["bb", "cc"]`.

What is the best way to do it in D?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` and `canFind` support a variadic number of needles, so using them is the easiest:

```d
"aabbccddffgg".canFind("bb", "cc");
```

Learn more about [std.algorithm.searching.canFind here](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.canFind).
If you don't know the number of needles at *compile-time*, it depends a bit on how much you know about the string, but the naive approach would be to loop multiple times over the string:

```d
auto eles = ["bb", "cc"];
eles.any!(e => "aabbccddffgg".canFind(e)))
```

If you know more about the sub elements, there are better approaches.
For example, if you know that all needles have all the length n, you could create a sliding window of size n and check whether your needles occur in one of the sliding windows:

```d
auto eles = ["bb", "cc"];
"aabbccddffgg".slide(2).canFind!(e => eles.canFind!equal(e));
```

Learn more about [std.range.slide here](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#slide).
The same idea also works in the general case:

```d
auto eles = ["bb", "cc"];
string s = "aabbccddffgg";
s.enumerate
   .map!(e => s.drop(e.index))
   .canFind!(e => eles.canFind!(reverseArgs!startsWith)(e));
```

Note that `drop` uses slicing and happens lazily in O(1) without any memory allocation.

Of course, there are still more efficient approaches with more advanced string matching algorithms.